# Mocking in python

Tags: python

I am trying to mock below method, but not able to do it.

data_test.py:

```
def test1:
    res = get_url(url)
    status_code = res.status_code
    if status_code == http.HTTPStatus.OK:
         response_data = res.json()


def get_url(url):
    resp = requests.request('GET', url, header=self.header)
    return resp
```

test-data_test.py (mocking file)

```
    @mock.patch("data_test.get_url")
    @mock.patch("requests.get")
    def test_01_check_database(self, mock_get, gurl):
        gurl.return_value.json.return_value = {'status':http.HTTPStatus.OK,'data':{'data':'data'}}
```

However, the above code gives error as the value of "res" is None. Can anyone help me to sort out this code? I need to mock to get correct HTTP status OK resp and also return the resp.json values.

Comment: `get_url` doesn't actually return anything

Comment: also, pretty sure the kwarg is `headers` not `header` in `requests.request()`. Furthermore, if you are always going to be using GET, you can use `requests.get()` instead.

Comment: get_url returns resp(i have edited the above example)
also note that i have changed the code, actually get_url does POST. GET also.

Comment: Why do you mock `requests.get` ?

Comment: Then whats the solution ?